# How to handle dynamic overlay using webdriver

Tags: webdriver

While executing a selenium script, we are getting a overlay (like popup) which is asking to confirm yes or no.
In this case the main problem being the Overlay popup does not come at a constant place,instead it comes at differen places.
example :- consider we have 4 pages to navigate some time it comes in first page and some times it comes in second page, and sometimes
it comes in the same page while we are accessing different elements.sometimes we are not getting overlay.

please let me know how to solve this issue, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that through driver options, at least in Internet Explorer. This is how I do in `Selenium`.NET binding

```
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions { EnableNativeEvents = false };
options.UnexpectedAlertBehavior = InternetExplorerUnexpectedAlertBehavior.Dismiss;
```

It will force close any unexpected pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is correct solution, but this must solution of your task.

You can create simple function(method) that checks for existence of this popup with some timeout. And put in in all possible places.

Or you can check it by some timer in another thread(with pause of main thread)